# jQuery Validation Plugin Add Logic To Ignore Option

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How can I add logic to ignore option, I know that I can do the following:

```
ignore: ":hidden"
ignore: ":hidden:not(.my_item), .area"
.
.
.
```

I want to add logic to the ignore option, for example the following html:

```
<div class="con-logic" style="display: none;">
    <div class="section">
        <label for="content" class="field-label">
            <textarea title="reeeq" class="textarea required area" style="height: 200px; display: none;" autocomplete="off" cols="40" name="content" id="content"></textarea>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to ignore this textarea field if the div with the class con-logic is hidden.

PS:the textarea for the iframe.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's already how this plugin works by default.  You don't need `ignore` option nor any special logic.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, the textarea for the iframe. I just edit my question.

Comment: **Quote OP**:  _"PS:the textarea for the iframe."_  ~ What are you talking about?  I don't see any `iframe` here.

Comment: If the plugin do that by default why I asked my question?

Comment: I needed to do that on the above html.

Comment: I have no idea why you asked the question... because clearly the plugin already does this by default.  Can you not see this jsFiddle?   http://jsfiddle.net/4n448ycj

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if (!$(".con-logic").css('display') == 'none') {
// ...
}
```

Try this hope it will help.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a lot of divs with class con-logic I just want it for this textarea that have the class area.

Comment: What about the ignore option?

Comment: You can user id for the div of text area

Comment: You can add validation is side this if condition. That mean it will only execute if div is not hidden. hope it will work for you.

Comment: `$(".con-logic").is(':hidden')` is much cleaner.

Comment: I just added some modification to the answer

Comment: if (!$(".con-logic").css('display') == 'none') {
$(".area").removeClass('required')
}

Answer (score 0):

You cannot "add logic" to dynamically toggle the jQuery Validate `ignore` option based on a condition or anything else.  This option only takes a jQuery selector, and once `.validate()` is called, the option cannot be changed.

**Quote OP**:

> "I want to ignore this textarea field if the div with the class con-logic is hidden."

That's already how this plugin works by default.  You don't need `ignore` option nor any special logic.

Based on the HTML you posted, the `textarea` would be hidden since it's inside a hidden parent container.   Because the jQuery Validate plugin automatically ignores all hidden input elements, it is already behaving exactly like you request.

**DEMO (parent `div` hidden):  http://jsfiddle.net/4n448ycj**

**DEMO (parent `div` shown):  http://jsfiddle.net/4n448ycj/1/**

As you dynamically toggle the visibility of the parent element, the behavior of the jQuery Validate plugin will properly follow.

**DEMO (toggle `div`):  http://jsfiddle.net/4n448ycj/2/**

---

**EDIT**:

**Quote Edited OP**:

> "PS:the textarea for the iframe."

What `iframe`?... there is no `iframe` shown in your OP.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I think because the textarea for the iframe the jQuery Validate plugin doesn't behave like my request.

Comment: @Engr.MTH, What `iframe`? You didn't mention anything about an `iframe` in your question.